# Please combine or synonym tag: [air-conditioning] and [cooling]

Tags: discussion, support, status-deferred, tag-synonyms

Please synonym [air-conditioning](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioning) and [cooling](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling).  Because of varying climates, I think it's appropriate to treat different environmental conditioning elements separately (i.e. [heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating), [cooling](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling), (proposing tag) [ventilation]).  So in this sense, air-conditioning and cooling should be synonyms.  If something less specific is meant by "air-conditioning," then the precise tag should be used.

Comment: Air-conditioning may control not only temperature but also humidity.  Personally, for cooling I think of a fridge or freezer, and for air-conditioning I think of spaces where humans or other living beings (or perhaps computers) reside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's potentially a good idea.

It does set me wondering about what people mean by these terms. As gerrit mentions in a comment, cooling can refer to refrigeration and freezers.

Furthermore, air-conditioning includes dehumidification as well as cooling; it can include humidification and air-filtering too.

So, we've got a bunch of topics with partially overlapping tags (where the tags already exist, or could do):

[heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating) [hvac](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hvac) [ventilation](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ventilation) [air-conditioning](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioning) [humidity-control](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humidity-control) [cooling](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling) [refrigeration](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refrigeration) [freezing](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freezing)

I'm minded, for now, to leave things as they are, watch how they evolve, and come back to it when we've got more questions on this family of tags, to see if there's a clearer pattern. And I'm also happy to go with what the community decides, if we get a clear signal before then.

Comment: I think HVAC could be synonymed to ventilation or air conditioning... but agreed on keeping the rest separate for now