# Is air-conditioning a synonym for cooling?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have two separate tags, [cooling](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling) and [air-conditioning](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioning). Right now these are not synonyms, but I wonder if they should be.

#### Precedent

The inverse tags, [heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating) and [space-heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-heating) have already been synonomized in 2017. It does feel like we should be consistent in our application of synonyms here.

#### Previous Discussion

- [Please combine or synonym tag: [air-conditioning] and [cooling]](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201/please-combine-or-synonym-tag-air-conditioning-and-cooling)
- [Heating tag is only for space-heating or not?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204/heating-tag-is-only-for-space-heating-or-not)

Comment: I think a synonym is the way to go.

Comment: @LShaver Why not write that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't be a synonym. That is, in careful technical usage, they mean different things.

Cooling can be done without air conditioning.

Air conditioning can be done without cooling the room: keeping the relative humidity within a set range is part of what air conditioning does.

Comment: In that case, do you think the tag synonym for [space-heating] should be undone?

Comment: I see your point. Of the questions with [both tags](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioning+cooling), it looks like only [this one](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/how-effective-is-free-cooling) doesn't need both

Comment: I also tend to agree that it's not a synonym. We currently have 23 questions tagged with cooling and only a few of those are about air conditioning. The case with heating/space-heating is different. When we merged those tags almost all questions tagged with heating were in fact about space-heating.